# Homeomorphism between $\Bbb R$ − {$1$} and nodal curve

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, connections

I have difficulty to solve this exercise of topology:
Consider $X = \Bbb R$ − {$1$}, $Y = {y^2 = x^2 + x^3} ⊂ \Bbb R^2$ and $f : X → Y$, $f(t)=(t^2−1,t^3−t)$.Show that $f$ is continuous and bijective,that any $x∈X$ has a neighbourhood $U$ such that $f : U → f (U )$ is a homeomorphism.

I have difficulty to show the last part. I've that $f$ isn't closed therefore $f$ isn't an homeomorphism. Another question: when I show that function is continuous because $\Bbb R$ − {$1$} is disconnected also the nodal curve is disconnected but it seems connected to me. How can I show that the nodal curve is disconnected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it is connected.  The point $(0, 0)$ would be the image of $-1$ and $1$, but removing $1$ still leaves $-1$.  But the topology of the nodal curve doesn't change; it still topologically is a circle wedge a line.  The circle is for $t$ between $-1$ and $1$, the wedge point is $(0, 0)$, and the line is from $(-\infty, -1]\cup(1, \infty)$.  So this cannot be a homeomorphism.  It's a continuous map as you said, but not bicontinuous.

Comment: What does "is a circle wedge a line." mean_

Comment: Sorry, that's topology terminology meaning taking a point on a circle and a point on a line and calling them the same point.  Gluing the two together at those points.

Comment: For the last part any ideas?

Comment: @DomenicoVuono the last part meaning that it's not connected?  If it's the wedge of a circle and a line, it has to be connected, since the circle and the line both are, so any disconnection would have to separate the two; but the wedge point must be in both the set containing the circle and the set containing the line, so the circle and line must be together.  So the disconnection is really nothing at all, and the set is connected.

Comment: No for the homeomorphism from U to f(U)

Comment: @Bo Thanks, I know topology yet I didn't understand the way you used. "Wedge point" (or whatever) is something I know.

Comment: @DomenicoVuono It's just sort of like, looking at where neighborhoods go, what could go wrong?  If we stay away from 1, then there's no possibility of overlap at the node, so as long as we take a neighborhood $U$ around the point $x$ that doesn't include $1$, the neighborhood maps homeomorphically onto its image.  The inverse is even $(x, y)\rightarrow \frac{y}{x}$, and $(0, 0)\rightarrow -1$.  This is a continuous map wherever you define it, as long as you stay away from the other points that surround $(0, 0)$.